# iOS Instruments Allocations Net/Overall

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, allocation

I have been tested my app with instruments allocations and get this picture:
[image]
Like graphic shows, my app work normally, but is it normally value in overall bytes? And I'm worry about "#Allocations (Net/Overall)", because it's color is red.What is it mean (red color)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Red is the total (Overall) allocations made and deallocated during all your App's runtime.

Purple (really thin bar over the red one) are the allocated and not yet deallocated objects.

I would say that you don't need to worry too much about it, specially for internal objects or `Malloc`, and focus indeed on higher level objects such as views and controllers.

---

Also if you click on the Allocations tool's `i` you can choose to ignore `CF` (Core Foundation) or `Malloc` allocations, which I often do as you don't normally deal directly/don't have control over those allocations.

Again as you improve your higher level objects allocations you'll be indirectly improving those underlying allocations as well.

Comment: A nice way to filter the huge list of allocations is to sort by `category` not `#`, and than scroll down to all the allocations with your class prefixes... When everything in there looks good, I move on to the UI and CG class prefixes. Helps getting a better understanding of the huge mess in that list...